# vertical align у inline-block

Tags: html, css

Не могу понять, как работает способ вертикального центрирования.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mws18yoL/)

```css
.parent {
    height:100px;
    width:600px;
    border:1px solid #ff0000;
}

.helper {
    display:inline-block;
    height:100%;
    width:1px;
    background:green;
}

.child {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
    border:1px solid #0000ff;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="helper"></div>
    <div class="child">TEXT</div>
</div>
```

Если дать элементу .helper vertical-align:middle, то центрируется отлично. Без этого нет. Но ведь должно и без того?

Высота строки задана блоком .helper в 100% от родителя. Далее известно следующее - vertical-align:middle - выравнивание средней точки элемента по базовой линии родителя плюс половина высоты родительского элемента. Базовая линия - по низу .helper + половина высоты родительского элемента. Следуя этому элемент .child должен быть сейчас центрирован, однако на деле он просто сопоставил свою середину с базовой линией. Объясните пожалуйста, чего я не понимаю??

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Так как блоки display:inline-block; пытаються по документации строиться друг за другом, то ставить им vertical-align надо соответственно иначе после блока vertical-align слежующий блок становиться типа bottom... как то так.
P.S. и лучше при использовании в строительстве inline-block не оставлять разрыв между блоками (пробел/перенос строки/ и т.д.) иначе будет отступ который вы тоже не будете понимать откуда он родился.

```css
.parent {
    height:100px;
    width:600px;  
    border:1px solid #ff0000;    
}

.helper {
    display:inline-block;
    height:100%;
    width:1px;
    background-color:green;
    vertical-align:middle;
}

.child {
    display:inline-block;        
    vertical-align:middle;    
    border:1px solid #0000ff;    
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="helper">
    </div><div class="child">TEXT</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

По спецификации: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-vertical-align

Самая последняя строка:

> The baseline of an 'inline-block' is the baseline of its last line box in the normal flow, unless it has either no in-flow line boxes or if its 'overflow' property has a computed value other than 'visible', in which case the baseline is the bottom margin edge.

Что в переводе означает что-то вроде: Базовая линия инлайн блока — это базовая линия последнего текстового блока в обычном контексте, иначе базовая линия это нижний край.

Comment: Да, но, если я в данном случае дам блоку .helper vertical-align:middle, как это повлияет на базовую линию то?